# getting issue while zipaligning large(size) apk "Unable to open 'path/app_name.apk' as zip archive"

Tags: android, ant, apk

This procedure fails with large size apk but works fine with smaller apk sizes. I have tried this procedure with 1/3rd of data content in it and it works successfully. Size of signed apk is around 350MB.